# docker-compose external build context with relative dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

What I'm trying to accomplish is this: I want to cache the current users `~/.aws` directory inside a container so that I can use them during the build of another container.

I have the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  worker:
    depends_on:
      - aws
  aws:
    build:
      context: ~/.aws
      dockerfile: ./ctx.dockerfile
      args:
        - workdir=/root/.aws
```

These are the contents of `ctx.dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:3.9

ARG workdir
WORKDIR ${workdir}

COPY . .
```

And in my `worker` service Dockerfile I have the following:

```
...
COPY --from=aws_ctx:local /root/.aws /root/.aws
...
```

### The Problem

docker compose isn't treating the `dockerfile` path in the `aws` service as relative to the docker-compose.yml, it is instead assuming it is relative to the `context` path. Is there anyway I can have docker-compose load the `ctx.dockerfile` from same directory as docker-compose.yml AND set the context the way that I am?

I'm up for changing my approach to the problem, but I have a few contstraints:

1. any solution must be workable on Windows, OSX, and Linux
2. any solution must only require docker and/or docker-compose, I can't run a shell script beforehand

Comment: Does the answer sovle your problem or do you need any further help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anyway I can have docker-compose load the ctx.dockerfile from same directory as docker-compose.yml AND set the context the way that I am?

AFAIK: No, there isn't.

Everything that the Dockerfile interacts with on build time must be in the defined context. So, you need `.aws` and the current folder where the `docker-compose.yml` etc. lives to be in the same context, i.e. the context would need to be the highest level of your relevant directory structure and then you would have to define relative paths to the files you need (the Dockerfiles and `.aws`).

Maybe you *could* set `/home/$USER` as your build context (or even higher level, depending on where your Dockerfiles etc. live), but then you would also have to create a `.dockerignore` file and ignore *everything* in the context besides `.aws` and the current folder... As you can see, this would be a mess and not very reproducible.

I would suggest to use a volume instead of `COPY`ing the `~/.aws` folder inside your container.

**Example:**

```
nico@lapap12:~$ ls -l ~/.aws
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 nico nico 0 May 22 17:45 foo.bar
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  allinone:
    image: alpine:latest
    volumes:
      - ~/.aws:/tmp/aws:ro
    command: ls -l /tmp/aws
```

```
nico@lapap12:~/local/so$ docker-compose up
Creating so_allinone_1 ... done
Attaching to so_allinone_1
allinone_1  | total 0
allinone_1  | -rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000             0 May 22 15:45 foo.bar
so_allinone_1 exited with code 0
```

You could go from there and copy the content of `/tmp/aws` to `/root/.aws` if you want to change this folder's content in the container, but don't want to touch it on the actual host.